# MQTT on ESP8266 cannot connect if using Last Will service

Tags: esp8266, mqtt

## Issue (short) description

An ESP8266 using PubSubClient fails to establish connection to MQTT broker (mosquitto) if requesting Last Will Testament (LWT) on connection, though it is able to connect without LWT.

## The aim and detailed description of the issue

The aim is actually to make the ESP to receive messages that been published while it was offline. Following [the generic recipe for MQTT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34152167/6033228), I tried to set `cleanSession =false` [which in `PubSubClient` also requires passing LWT arguments](https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api#connect). Using code shown bellow (with the arguments passed to the `PubSubClient.connect()` method)  results in that the same ESP board connecting to the same MQTT server could not connect anymore (the code below is stripped to MQTT relevant parts):

```
WiFiClient wclient;
PubSubClient mqtt_client(wclient);

String DEVICE_NAME = "esp8266_test";
const int DEVICE_ID = 1;
String MQTT_CLIENT_ID = DEVICE_NAME + (String)(DEVICE_ID);

const char * mqtt_client_id = MQTT_CLIENT_ID.c_str();
const char* willTopic = (DEVICE_NAME + "/will").c_str();
uint8_t willQos = 0;
bool willRetain = false;
const char* willMessage = "will";
bool cleanSession = false;
int mqtt_keep_alive = 60;

void connect_mqtt(const char *mqtt_user, const char *mqtt_pass, const int timeout){
  int i = 0;
  logger.info("Connecting to MQTT broker.");
  while ((!mqtt_client.connected()) && (i < timeout) && (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
    logger.info("Attempt " + (String)(++i));
    mqtt_client.setKeepAlive(mqtt_keep_alive);
    mqtt_client.connect(
      mqtt_client_id,
      mqtt_user,
      mqtt_pass,
      willTopic,
      willQos,
      willRetain,
      willMessage,
      cleanSession);
  }
  
  if (mqtt_client.connected()) {
        logger.info("MQTT broker connected.");
    } else {
        logger.error("Connection timeout. Failed with state: " + (String)(mqtt_client.state()));
        }
}

void start_mqtt(IPAddress mqtt_server, const int mqtt_port, const char *mqtt_user, const char *mqtt_pass){
  
  mqtt_client.setServer(mqtt_server, mqtt_port);
  // mqtt_client.setCallback(callback);
  connect_mqtt(mqtt_user, mqtt_pass, timeout);  
}
```

In the code above `start_mqtt()` function is called from `setup()`, the output it will result in looks as follows:

```
INFO: Connecting to WIFI SSID: xxxxxxx
INFO: WiFi Connection established
IP address:     192.168.178.55
INFO: Connecting to MQTT broker.
INFO: Attempt 1
INFO: Attempt 2
INFO: Attempt 3
INFO: Attempt 4
INFO: Attempt 5
INFO: Attempt 6
ERROR: Connection timeout. Failed with state: -4
```

If instead one calls `connect()` method with only `mqtt_client_id, mqtt_user, mqtt_pass` arguments, the connection can be established without any issues, e.g.:

```
mqtt_client.connect(mqtt_client_id, mqtt_user, mqtt_pass)
```

## Attempts to troubleshoot:

- I've tried using `connect()` without `cleanSession` argument, the behaviour is the same: cannot connect with state `-4`. So I've concluded that the issue is in LWT service, which I actually don't need but it [seems one has to use it with `cleanSession`](https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api#connect)
- According to [PubSubClient documentation](https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api#state) the `-4` state is "the server didn't respond within the keepalive time", so I've started looking on the server side (see next items)
- The server log looks like this:

```
2023-04-01 18:37:09 1680367029: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
2023-04-01 18:38:36 1680367116: New connection from 172.17.0.1:54174 on port 1883.
```

- If connecting without LWT (using only `mqtt_client_id`, `mqtt_user`, `mqtt_pass` arguments) connection can be established and the log looks like this:

```
2023-04-01 18:38:36 1680367116: New client connected from 172.17.0.1:54174 as esp8266_test1 (p2, c1, k60, u'xxxx').
```

- [Mosquitto documentation](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) doesn't say anything about enabling LWT, which suggests that it should work with the mostly default config which is used here.
- I tried two different Mosquitto servers configured for user/password authentication, results are the same.

## Questions

Based on behaviour above, my conclusion is that using PubSubClient with LWT results in a sort of change of a protocol which is not recognised/supported by Mosquitto. Therefore, the questions are:

1. Is there is a way to fix the issue, or to further troubleshoot it?
2. Is there is a way to use `cleanSession = false` without enabling LWT?
3. Is there other ways of receiving "offline" MQTT messages on ESP8266 (without using `cleanSession = false`)?

Comment: Hi @Vadim - could you please edit the question to include the values you're using for `willTopic`, `willQos`, `willRetain` and `willMessage`?

Comment: @romkey sure, done